# On topic to ask for feedback on draft of degree project report?

Tags: support, specific-question

I do a degree project in computer science. We are around halfway done. I'd like somebody who is knowledgeable to give feedback on our work so far.

Could that be on topic for this site or somewhere else on SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is off-topic here because it is about the content of your specific field and not about academia. It’s also not suited for any other site on the network because it’s a request for unspecific critique and not for information.

In fact, I doubt that you will find anybody on the Internet doing this work voluntarily, because only somebody familiar with your specific field can do this and it is a considerable amount of work.

The person who can and should give you feedback on this is your supervisor, or at least some senior member of their work group. You may also get feedback from a fellow student, but they may not be capable to spot certain problems.